# I have two sql columns that have integer values, so how can i set to increase for 1 without manually insert data?

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2012

I have two sql columns that have integer values, so how can i set to increase for 1 without manually insert data?

```
public bool changeData(classIP CIobject)
        {
        bool check = false;

        clConnection clConn = new clConnection();
        SqlConnection conn = clConn.openConnection();

        SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand();
        comm.Connection = conn;
        comm.CommandText = "UPDATE userTBL SET SifraPrimac=@SifraPrimac, SifraIsplakac=@SifraIsplakac";
```

I need to add values for SifraPrimac and SifraIsplakac by increasing for one

```
 comm.Parameters.Add("@SifraPrimac", SqlDbType.Int).Value = CIobject.SifraPrimac;
    comm.Parameters.Add("@SifraIsplakac", SqlDbType.Int).Value = CIobject.SifraIsplakac;


        if (comm.ExecuteNonQuery() >= 0)
        {
            check = true;

        }
        comm.Dispose();

        return check;
    }
```

Comment: If you want to increment the value by one over the existing value, for all rows: `UPDATE userTBL SET SifraPrimac = SifraPrimac + 1, SifraIsplakac = SifraIsplakac + 1`, or are you trying to do something more specific than that?

Comment: @Diado ahh beat me to it :D

Comment: i`m trying to insert new record, and want to take last number from the column and increase it for 1, just like id, but i cant make it key because there are two columns with integer values.

Comment: Maybe you should show us how your table looks like.
But from what I understand you can use the SQL `MAX()` function https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_min_max.asp
And then you want to use the SQL `INSERT` if you want a new row. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp

Comment: You have a couple of choices depending on what DBMS you're using. If it's SQL Server 2012+ you can create a [Sequence](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) for each value you want to increment, and then use [Next Value For](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/next-value-for-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) when you insert the data, or create a default based on the sequence.. You can also use a sub-query using `SELECT MAX(columnName)...` and then add one to it. There may be other options in other DBMSes too.

Comment: @k.Lennartz thanks a lot it was helpful. i`ve done it that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to get their values add 1 in c# and then set the values again. just let do the adding in your SQL query.

```
  clConnection clConn = new clConnection();
            SqlConnection conn = clConn.openConnection();

            SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand();
            comm.Connection = conn;
comm.CommandText = "UPDATE userTBL SET SifraPrimac=SifraPrimac+1, SifraIsplakac=SifraIsplakac+1";
    comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
```